# GraphQL mutation with empty array with React and AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm trying to create a 'User' that has an array of 'lists'. When I try to first create the user, I wanted to have an empty 'lists' array so that I can add to it later.

Here's my schema:

```
type User @model {
  id: String!
  email: String!
  lists: [List] @connection(name: "UserLists")
}

type List @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  owner: User! @connection(name: "UserLists")
}
```

Here's the createUser mutation function:

```
export const createUser = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CreateUser(
    $input: CreateUserInput!
    $condition: ModelUserConditionInput
  ) {
    createUser(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      email
      lists {
        items {
          id
          name
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        nextToken
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

Here's the call I'm trying to make:

```
let input = {
    input: {
       email: 'test@test.com',
       id: 'ab953afe',
       lists: [],
     },
};

await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createUser, input));
```

And I'm getting this error:

**"The variables input contains a field name 'lists' … defined for input object type 'CreateUserInput' "**

I am able to create a new user if I omit anything for 'lists'.

Any ideas why I'm seeing this error and how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

just remove `list: []` from input

```
const input = {
    input: {
       email: 'test@test.com',
       id: 'ab953afe',
     },
};

await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createUser, input));
```

Comment: How do i regenerate the mutations and queries after i make modifications to schema.json